# How to do a RewriteRule for multiple file extensions as .(html|htm|php)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to do a RewriteRule like this, for multiple file extensions as .(html|htm|php)?

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ directory/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect anything that ends with .html, .htm or .php to directory/index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(html|htm|php))$ directory/index.php [L]
```